# PHP MySQL PDO v.s. MySQL Workbench (PHP over 20x slower?)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-workbench, benchmarking

I am timing the execution time of a query, since PHP performs way slower than my MySQL Workbench.

When I execute a particular query in MySQL Workbench, it comes back with below results and statistics:

```
455 row(s) returned
Duration 0.047 sec
Fetch time 0.069 sec
```

However, when I perform the exact same query in PHP the execution takes way longer (**over 20x with below results?**):

```
455 row(s) returned
Duration 2,3708 sec
Fetch time ? //how could I determine this in PHP?
```

The code I use to measure the duration in PHP:

```
$query = $mysqli_pdo->prepare($query);
$query->bindValue //(about 500 binds performed, which are also performed in MySQL Workbench)
echo microtime(true),"|QUERY START\n");
$query->execute();
echo microtime(true),"|QUERY END\n");
```

Which returns me:

```
1507207267,9878|QUERY START
1507207270,3586|QUERY END
```

resulting in a duration of 2,3708 sec

Testing conditions:

- PHP7.0.24 and MySQL run on the same server
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache 2.4
- Exact same query (SELECT ONLY)
- Connected via UNIX Socket

**How can this be such a huge difference looking at performance and how can I reduce this quite extreme difference?**

Comment: @JayBlanchard, added the actual question...

Comment: I think it's because there's the PDO layer between PHP and Database which is not the case in the MySQL Workbench, which is more like SSHing to the server and interacting with MySQL directly.. I'm not sure though

Comment: @teeyo, possible. However, is there a better way - looking at performance - to decrease PHP's duration time?

Comment: Have you run an EXPLAIN on the query? Are you suing the indexes properly?

Comment: We don't know where your MySQL "sits" and where PHP "sits" - same server? Remote server? We can't tell whether queries done via workbench hit the cache or not. We don't know the network roundtrip for queries done via PHP. We don't know if Workbench disregards the time required to send the data, and if it only returns prints out what MySQL terminal would (it does). As you can see, there's quite a bit we don't know. It could be a simple matter of network delay between PHP and MySQL, due to handshake, dns, what-not. But - we don't know. There's not enough information.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, yes and it is using the indexes. Besides that, else MySQL Workbench wouldn't perform so well?

Comment: @Mjh, good comment. I added some known testing conditions

Comment: How do you connect to MySQL from PHP? Is it a TCP socket (127.0.0.1:3306) or unix socket (`/var/sock/mysql.sock` or similar)? You should eliminate network delay first and assert that PHP wastes time. I suspect it might be a network related issue, that's what I'd eliminate first. The query in question is a select or insert or a combination of everything?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using anyway ?

Comment: @Mjh, I connect via UNIX Socket

Comment: @teeyo, PHP7.0.24

Comment: What do you mean by `(about 500 binds performed, which are also performed in MySQL Workbench)`?

Comment: @Narf, I mean that the query contains about 500 parameters, bound with the function in PHP

Comment: Right, so you're using the browser to run the script via Apache. Any chance you can create a CLI version of the script and run it through the terminal and assert it's still slow compared to direct MySQL connection?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren That part I get; I'm interested in the workbench part of that comment ...

Comment: So your question is not "PDO is slow" but "I have insane number of parameters and it's slow". Could you please kindly change the title to something more relevant?

Comment: @mjh, correct. I don't have the option to make a CLI.

Comment: @Narf, the parameters are just in the query itself. like WHERE x=a etc.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, no not really. I don't mind the amount of parameters, as stated above. It's just an example query in order to determine the duration and difference

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren If you directly type-in the params in question while in Workbench, that is not the same thing as doing binds. Bound parameters are sent to the server *separately* from the query, adding more network roundtrips - that's almost certainly where the difference comes from.

Comment: An example query ought to be exactly freaking the same as one you are running in workbench, to the last freaking comma. Everything else you have a whim to introduce make your results absolutely pointless.

Comment: @Narf, you fixed the issue thanks now the duration is almost equal! Please answer the question so I can accept your answer

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren The question doesn't solve any problem other than your quriosity ... Just delete it, or post the answer yourself if that's what you prefer.